# Is there any source to search for spring boot starter dependencies?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependencies

I want to use "feign" dependency in my spring boot project, Is there any source like https://mvnrepository.com/ to get dependency?

Comment: Generally http://start.spring.io is a place to start, also the [reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-starter) has a list of starters.

Comment: Dear @M.Deinum I want add dependency for already generated project

Comment: You can still use start.spring.io , download the project and copy the selected depenency location to your own pom. Or as stated look at the reference guide which has a pointer to the available starters.

Comment: Every time when i need some dependency do i need to down load a project.? I don't think it is feasible solution..

Comment: I found that if we have STS(Spring tools eclipse plugin) just Ctrl+Space in pom.xml we can see **Edit Starters** there we can pick..

Comment: The dependencies are mentioned in the reference guide (follow the link I added to the first comment). The code completion **might** work but only if you keep indexing the maven repositories, if you don't it eventually will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that,we can search search same in https://mvnrepository.com/ with spring suffix
Ex: **feign spring**

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring initializer. https://start.spring.io/. I would suggest you to always use one version lower than the latest version of snapshot. Cause newer version might not be that standard.

Comment: I came across a website when I was in troubled with same thing. https://crunchify.com/how-to-import-all-spring-mvc-dependencies-to-your-maven-project/. Here you have instructions to import spring dependencies. Hope it might help you

Answer (score 0):

You may use spring initializer i.e https://start.spring.io/. Go to the site and fill in all the details.Select the dependency you want(in your case feign). Select generate. It will generate a zip file with your starter project. Import it and you can start coding.You can see a picture demonstrating the same in this link [The spring initializer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eil3.png)

Alternatively you can do the same using Spring tool suite. You can download STS here [Spring Tool Suite](https://spring.io/tools3/sts/all).
->Install and open spring tool suite.
->Click File>>New and select spring starter project. If u don't get the option there, choose other and then search for spring starter project.
->After choosing spring starter project, fill in all the necessary details and click next.
->In the next section choose all the dependencies you require(in your case feign).
->click finish and you are good to go.

Happy Coding.

Comment: @NarendarReddyM Just google feign maven dependency. You will get the code there. Just paste it in the dependencies tag in the POM.xml. Update the project and its done.